# Upload data on google spreadsheets using java

Tags: java, gdata, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to upload data onto google spreadhsheets using Atom technique. Can anyone guide me how can I do that? I want to make a core java based solution. So far I have figured out the way to enter data using ListEntry, but using Atom I have no idea what to do?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the updated Spreadsheets API documentation at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets, all samples include a Protocol tab describing the raw XML request to be sent to perform that task.